# Cannot plot a list in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have this data files:

```
 data1 = {{3.06122, 10000., 0.629892}, {3.06122, 11836.7, 0.590095}, {3.06122, 
13673.5, 0.55436}, {3.06122, 15510.2, 0.522086}, {3.06122, 17346.9, 
0.492813}, {3.06122, 19183.7, 0.466156}, {3.06122, 21020.4, 
0.441802}, {3.06122, 22857.1, 0.419489}, {3.06122, 24693.9, 
0.398983}, {3.06122, 26530.6, 0.380088}, {3.06122, 28367.3, 
0.362635}, {3.06122, 30204.1, 0.346477}, {3.06122, 32040.8, 
0.33148}, {3.06122, 33877.6, 0.317532}, {3.06122, 35714.3, 
0.304534}, {3.06122, 37551., 0.292397}, {3.06122, 39387.8, 
0.281043}, {3.06122, 41224.5, 0.270404}, {3.06122, 43061.2, 
0.260416}, {3.06122, 44898., 0.251027}, {3.06122, 46734.7, 
0.242185}, {3.06122, 48571.4, 0.233848}, {3.06122, 50408.2, 
0.225977}, {3.06122, 52244.9, 0.218535}, {3.06122, 54081.6, 
0.211491}, {3.06122, 55918.4, 0.20481}, {3.06122, 57755.1, 
0.198475}, {3.06122, 59591.8, 0.192454}, {3.06122, 61428.6, 
0.186732}, {3.06122, 63265.3, 0.181285}, {3.06122, 65102., 
0.176093}, {3.06122, 66938.8, 0.171143}, {3.06122, 68775.5, 
0.166419}, {3.06122, 70612.2, 0.161905}, {3.06122, 72449., 
0.157591}, {3.06122, 74285.7, 0.153461}, {3.06122, 76122.4, 
0.149508}, {3.06122, 77959.2, 0.14572}, {3.06122, 79795.9, 
0.142087}, {3.06122, 81632.7, 0.1386}, {3.06122, 83469.4, 
0.135253}, {3.06122, 85306.1, 0.132036}, {3.06122, 87142.9, 
0.128947}, {3.06122, 88979.6, 0.125967}, {3.06122, 90816.3, 
0.123105}, {3.06122, 92653.1, 0.120346}, {3.06122, 94489.8, 
0.117688}, {3.06122, 96326.5, 0.115127}, {3.06122, 98163.3, 
0.112655}, {3.06122, 100000., 0.110269}}

data2 = {{1.63265, 10000., 0.629892}, {1.63265, 11836.7, 0.590095}, {1.63265, 
  13673.5, 0.55436}, {1.63265, 15510.2, 0.522086}, {1.63265, 17346.9, 
  0.492813}, {1.63265, 19183.7, 0.466156}, {1.63265, 21020.4, 
  0.441802}, {1.63265, 22857.1, 0.419489}, {1.63265, 24693.9, 
  0.398983}, {1.63265, 26530.6, 0.380088}, {1.63265, 28367.3, 
  0.362635}, {1.63265, 30204.1, 0.346477}, {1.63265, 32040.8, 
  0.33148}, {1.63265, 33877.6, 0.317532}, {1.63265, 35714.3, 
  0.304534}, {1.63265, 37551., 0.292397}, {1.63265, 39387.8, 
  0.281043}, {1.63265, 41224.5, 0.270404}, {1.63265, 43061.2, 
  0.260416}, {1.63265, 44898., 0.251027}, {1.63265, 46734.7, 
  0.242185}, {1.63265, 48571.4, 0.233848}, {1.63265, 50408.2, 
  0.225977}, {1.63265, 52244.9, 0.218535}, {1.63265, 54081.6, 
  0.211491}, {1.63265, 55918.4, 0.20481}, {1.63265, 57755.1, 
  0.198475}, {1.63265, 59591.8, 0.192454}, {1.63265, 61428.6, 
  0.186732}, {1.63265, 63265.3, 0.181285}, {1.63265, 65102., 
  0.176093}, {1.63265, 66938.8, 0.171143}, {1.63265, 68775.5, 
  0.166419}, {1.63265, 70612.2, 0.161905}, {1.63265, 72449., 
  0.157591}, {1.63265, 74285.7, 0.153461}, {1.63265, 76122.4, 
  0.149508}, {1.63265, 77959.2, 0.14572}, {1.63265, 79795.9, 
  0.142087}, {1.63265, 81632.7, 0.1386}, {1.63265, 83469.4, 
  0.135253}, {1.63265, 85306.1, 0.132036}, {1.63265, 87142.9, 
  0.128947}, {1.63265, 88979.6, 0.125967}, {1.63265, 90816.3, 
  0.123105}, {1.63265, 92653.1, 0.120346}, {1.63265, 94489.8, 
  0.117688}, {1.63265, 96326.5, 0.115127}, {1.63265, 98163.3, 
  0.112655}, {1.63265, 100000., 0.110269}}
```

The first entry is the same for all points in `data1`, the same is true for `data2` too. I want to plot it in 3D, so I use:

```
ListPlot3D[{data1,data2}]
```

This is the result:

[image]

There is nothing!. If I delete the first entry I will get:

```
ListPlot[Table[Delete[data1[[i, All]], 1], {i, 1, 50}]]
```

[image]

How can I plot `data1` and `data2` in a 3D form?

I have another problem with `ArrayPlot`. I cannot plot `data1` and `data2` by `ArrayPlot` if I use `ColorFunction` option.

Suppose I have:

```
data3 =Flatten[Table[i + j + k, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 10}, {k, 1, 3}], 1]
```

The dimension is 50 by 3 like `data1` or `data2`.

If I use `ColorFunction` option, I get:

```
ArrayPlot[Flatten[Table[i + j + k, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 10}, {k, 1, 3}], 1],ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]
```

[image]

If I don't use `ColorFunction` option, I get:

[image]

I have this problem when I want to plot `data1`and `data2`. How can I resolve that?

Comment: `ListPointPlot3D[{data1, data2}]`?

Comment: @Öskå. That worked. Thank you. Could you please tell me how I can plot it as a two dimensional plot with the third entry as the indicator of the density or intensity? If I use `ArrayPlot` or `ListDensityPlot` it won't work. I think the problem is that the first entry is same for each data file.

Comment: Ermmm, I don't get what you mean.  Create a smaller example with the desired output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListPointPlot3D` will achieve your aim:

```
ListPointPlot3D\[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"data1", "data2"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
x = Rest /@ data1;

MatrixPlot[x, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To use the inbuilt color tables you could rescale your values to run from `0` to `1`:

```
x2 = Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose @ x];

MatrixPlot[x2, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I should have asked the other question you asked in a separate topic. Thank you for your answer.
Could you please tell me how I could use `SunsetColors` instead?

Comment: @yashar See edit of my answer.